# The karma hunter problem: why OPs with more than 1k rep should be able to delete answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

I recently posted this question:

[Where should AutoLayout code be placed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233400/where-should-autolayout-code-be-placed/21233555)

I was looking for a canonical answer, as the documentation is quite ambiguous on the matter.

The question got two answers in the following 10 minutes. One answer was plain wrong, the other answer didn't fundamentally answer the question.

The question was then marked as having two "answers", and didn't get any further answers from then on.

This is a common pattern we need to do something about:

1. OP posts a question.
2. Karma hunters rush on the question, write wrong or incomplete answers.
3. The question is *nonetheless* marked as having 2 answers and thus **dissuades competent answerers from posting**.

This is a problem, simply because we miss out on better quality answers.

Currently, only members with 10k+ rep or a diamond moderator can delete a bad answer. Their response time is, more often than not, too long.

I think the solution is simple: If an OP has more than 1k rep, they can be trusted to be knowledgeable about their field, can thus be trusted to distinguish between a good and a bad answer, and should therefore be able to *delete* a bad answer. Karma hunters will have to be competent for a change.

What do you people think?

Comment: 1k rep is way too easy to get. For example, by searching for a particular misspelling of a word and edit in a fix. You'd think the reviewers would notice, but no.

Comment: it is not 'karma', it is reputation, fundamentally different concepts. Do you have any data to verify point 3?

Comment: Deletion is a [10k tool, not 20k](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). If the answer is that bad it will attract downvotes. Questions with upvotes should be downvoted if they're wrong, not deleted.

Comment: @jmac wrong answers should be downvoted even if they have negative score and no upvotes.

Comment: @Jan, very true. Downvote all the poor answers regardless of current status. It feels good.

Comment: Perhaps you asked the wrong question? Most people are responding to questions because they think they know the answer. If you are getting the wrong answers, **improve your question**. Instead of blaming the people answering, take a good hard look if your question is perhaps missing information that could have lead to a better answer, instead.

Comment: I agree with problem, not with solution. Also, it's just a new description or maybe new aspect of the fastest gun in the west issue.

Comment: If I posted an answer that I believe to be correct and any OP no matter the rep decided to delete it I'd be annoyed - downvote and comment.

Answer (score 10):

I disagree with this 100%. If the answers are not complete or off topic then I they should be commented and flagged for moderation (when approriate). If you really dont get the answers you are looking for you should use the [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) system.

As others have commented the 1K mark is very simple to hit, especially if you have linked accounts gets you 100 immediately. Top that off with a few hundred edits and your there.

Comment: It should be clarified that answers should only be flagged for things like gibberish, follow-on questions, "me too" responses, etc. If they at all make an attempt to answer the question, those answers shouldn't be flagged. It's not up to moderators to make technical decisions about answers, just to clean out the stuff that obviously doesn't belong.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with this. If the given answers are wrong then downvote it. There is no option to delete a wrong answer which attempts to answer. Even we can't flag it as "Not an answer".

Your third point seems your opinion not a reality. Most people don't ignore a question (from the questions list) if it has some answers. They at least open the question and read both question and answer before taking some actions. I have seen many people answer the question even after it is accepted if they have better answer.

If you are not getting correct answers, probably you should

- make your question more clear
- tag it with appropriate tags
- if a question is difficult to answer you may start a bounty.

Answer (score 4):

What makes you so sure you know your subject matter? You have votes, **use them**. If others agree they are poor answers, then they'll accumulate downvotes too.

Deletion of posts is only reserved for posts that are off-topic or are not answers (asking a new question, should really have been a comment instead, spam, offensive content, etc.). If the answer is wrong, you downvote it.

What you should really ask yourself is what was unclear or incomplete about your *question* that attracted incorrect or incomplete answers in the first place. Try to improve your question, add clarifications and more detail; editing your post will bump it up the active questions page. You can also add a bounty to attract more attention.

Getting good answers in *your* responsibility. Don't try to blame it on the answerers.

Answer (score 2):

There are some basic structures for this. Like:

- You downvote if an answer is not sufficient or is wrong. Answers with negative scores generally deleted by the owner. Also users do not give much attention if an answer is negatively scored.
- You can leave comment stating what is wrong or missing with the answer. You can also state that the answer is wrong and tell what is wrong about it. Other users may downvote if they see your point.
- Users (must) check the other answers before writing their own answer since writing an answer with the same content with  another one will not get much reputation and probably be waste of answerer's time
- You can start a bounty if you want more attention.
- Finally, if you think the answer is (very much) wrong, then you can flag it as the last option.

For any reason, letting a user do delete some other users answer is not good idea (with very low reputation).

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the proposal. Giving the OP the authority to delete the answer will not always be fruitful.. Suppose some user gets frustrated of SE sites and decides to delete all the answers (good/bad).. what can you do then??? What OP thinks as best answer doesnt always has to be the only answer.. If you dislike the answer downvote(pass a comment if you want explaining) and move ahead

Im answering this regardless of reputation needed as mentioned..